# Send variable from one page to another in wordpress template

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to pass date from one wordpress template form to another. To make it simple, I have created two templates (and associated them with WP pages as a standard page) as follows:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Form test
*/
get_header(); 
?>

<form action="/form-result/" method="post">
<input type="text" name="name" size="20" />
<input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>

<a href="/form-result/">Result page</a>

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

and

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Form result
*/
get_header(); 
$name = $_REQUEST['name'];
?>

And the name is <?=$name?>

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

When I click on the text link Result page I get to the `/form-result/` page, however, if I submit the form, I get a page not found sort of error. After verifying, I found that the problem is coming from trying to pass the variable from one page to another.

Pusing further, I found that `<a href="/form-result/?name=Elodie">Result page</a>` get an error page whereas `<a href="/form-result/">Result page</a>` takes me properly to the next page.

Probably I am missing something small.

Any help here ?

Comment: Are you getting a "Page Not Found" (404) error or something else?

Comment: @s_ha_dum, sorry, updated.

Comment: Yes @Ken. That's exact.

Comment: You can usually tack `?anything=else` onto those URLs. I've been playing around with that to check. Something is peculiar about what you've done and I can't spot what based on the information provided.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is solved. It was that, the variable "name" that I was using for this test is a WP keyword and stands for template name. In the absence of template name it looks for other pages where the beginning of url slugs matches the variable name.

I changed the variable name and it worked as it should.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Form
*/
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>    

<form action="/form-result/" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="name" size="20" />
  <input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>

<a href="/form-result/">Result page</a>

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Modify your result page.

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Form Result
*/
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>    

<?php if(isset($_POST['name'])) {
  echo $_POST['name'];
} ?>

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the link to the results page inside the form like so:

```
<button type="submit" name="submitted" id="submitted" class="submit">Submit</button>
```

and on the results page:

```
if(isset($_POST['submitted'])) {
$name = $_POST['name'];

}
```

To pass form data you need to post the form via submit.
You can do this outside using jquery like this:

```
$el.click($('#form_name').submit());
```

-d

Comment: This is not helping @Darren.