# Set Form action in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, html, forms

I am creating form for wordpress website. Currently i am getting value on same page successfully with blank `action`.

Now i need to get form value on `data.php` page.

**Form**

```
<form id="post-container" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>data.php" method="POST">
   <input name="aa" value="post_id"> ........ </input>
   <input name="ab" value="post_id"> ........ </input>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

**data.php**

```
<?php 
if (isset ( $_POST['aa'] )){
  $ID = $_POST['aa'] ;
  echo get_post_meta( $ID, 'brand', true );
}

if (isset ( $_POST['ab'] )){
  $ID = $_POST['ab'] ;
  echo get_post_meta( $ID, 'brand', true );
}
?>
```

After submit

url = `http://localhost/mobile/data.php` which is correct.

but it display index.php which is wrong and also not print any value.

**How to submit form to data.php and print value?**

Comment: Show the files structure of data.php in wordpress

Note: try to use https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Comment: @TamilSelvanC i can't use Ajax. Please clear what do you mean by **show the files structure.....**

Comment: create your both pages as page template and assign them in to two WordPress pages and use the page URL as the action url

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9127054/how-to-pass-data-between-wordpress-pages

Comment: @ashanrupasinghe you means create two pages for both. and then these 2 put into one. Then this one use in action?

Comment: action='<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/data.php' >.  try this first

Comment: @ashanrupasinghe not work this ref to `http://localhost/mobile/wp-content/themes/mobile-theme/data.php`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15442095/send-variable-from-one-page-to-another-in-wordpress-template.   create page templates and try